Kotlin Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find implementation for com.example.tutorialfollowing.AppDatabase. AppDatabase_Impl does not exist
Iam new to coding in kotlin on android studio and I am currently trying to set up a room database for my project but iam getting a bunch of errors during runtime that iam not sure how to fix. The app is meant to display a list of names in a swipeable pager format, using Jetpack Compose for the UI, Room for local database storage,a ViewModel for app data management ,repository, ViewModelFactory for injecting the repository into view model and a database class for accessing the DAO.
Could you please tell me What I am missing or doing wrong?
Here is the list of errors iam receiving:
2024-06-23 10:13:58.120 26589-26589 System  com.example.tutorialfollowing   
W  ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.tutorialfollowing-2/lib/x86
2024-06-23 10:13:58.145 26589-26589 AndroidRuntime          com.example.tutorialfollowing       
 D  Shutting down VM
2024-06-23 10:13:58.145 26589-26589 AndroidRuntime       com.example.tutorialfollowing       
 E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main (Ask Gemini)
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.tutorialfollowing, PID: 26589
                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tutorialfollowing/com.example.tutorialfollowing.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find implementation for com.example.tutorialfollowing.AppDatabase. AppDatabase_Impl does not exist
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find implementation for com.example.tutorialfollowing.AppDatabase. AppDatabase_Impl does not exist
                                                                                                        at androidx.room.Room.getGeneratedImplementation(Room.kt:58)
                                                                                                        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase$Builder.build(RoomDatabase.kt:1351)
                                                                                                        at com.example.tutorialfollowing.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:54)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)

For context here is the code for my MainActivity.kt:
import android.os.Bundle
import android.content.res.Resources
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.activity.viewModels
import androidx.compose.foundation.ExperimentalFoundationApi
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.Orientation
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValues
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.pager.HorizontalPager
import androidx.compose.foundation.pager.rememberPagerState
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.foundation.pager.PageSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.pager.PagerDefaults
import androidx.compose.foundation.pager.PagerScope
import androidx.compose.material3.Scaffold
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.key
import androidx.compose.runtime.livedata.observeAsState
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.ContentScale
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

import com.example.tutorialfollowing.ui.theme.TutorialFollowingTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private lateinit var database: AppDatabase

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        database = Room.databaseBuilder(
            applicationContext,
            AppDatabase::class.java, "names-database"
        ).build()

        val nameDao = database.nameDao()
        val repository = NameRepository(nameDao)
        val viewModel: NameViewModel by viewModels { NameViewModelFactory(repository) }

        setContent {
            TutorialFollowingTheme {
                val names by viewModel.allNames.observeAsState(emptyList())
                NamePagerScreen(names)
            }
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun NamePagerScreen(names: List<Name>) {
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState(
        initialPage = 0,
        initialPageOffsetFraction = 0f
    ) {
        names.size
    }

    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        HorizontalPager(

            state = pagerState
        ) { page ->
            val name = names[page]
            val background = when (name.gender) {
                "Girl" -> R.drawable.pink
                "Boy" -> R.drawable.blue
                else -> R.drawable.default_background
            }

            Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(id = background),
                    contentDescription = null,
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                )
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .align(Alignment.Center)
                        .background(Color(0x80000000))
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(16.dp)
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = "${name.childFirstName} - ${name.gender}",
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineMedium,
                        color = Color.White,
                        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    TutorialFollowingTheme {
        NamePagerScreen(
            listOf(
                Name(1, 2020, "Girl", "Asian", "Lily", 10, 1),
                Name(2, 2020, "Boy", "Hispanic", "Joel", 8, 2)
            )
        )
    }
}

here is my data class 'Name.kt':
import androidx.room.ColumnInfo
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity(tableName = "names")
data class Name(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val nameId: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "year_of_birth") val yearOfBirth: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "gender") val gender: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "ethnicity") val ethnicity: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "child_first_name") val childFirstName: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "count") val count: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "rank") val rank: Int
)

Database class 'appDatabase'
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase

@Database(entities = [Name::class], version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase: RoomDatabase(){
    abstract fun nameDao(): NameDao
}

DAO interface file 'NameDao':
import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Insert
import androidx.room.Query
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow

@Dao
interface NameDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM names")
    fun getAll(): Flow<List<Name>>

    @Insert
    fun insertAll(vararg names: Name)
}

class 'NameRepository':
import androidx.annotation.WorkerThread
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow
class NameRepository(private val nameDao: NameDao) {
val allNames: Flow<List<Name>> = nameDao.getAll()

@WorkerThread
suspend fun insert(name: Name) {
    nameDao.insertAll(name)
}

}
Class 'NameViewModel':
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch


class NameViewModel (private val repository: NameRepository) : ViewModel() {

    private val _allNames = MutableLiveData<List<Name>>()
    val allNames: LiveData<List<Name>> = _allNames

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.allNames.collect { names ->
                _allNames.value = names
            }
        }
    }

    fun insert(name: Name) = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.insert(name)
    }
}

class file 'NameViewModelFactory' :
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider

class NameViewModelFactory(private val repository: NameRepository) : ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory() {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(NameViewModel::class.java)) {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return NameViewModel(repository) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }
}

libs.Versions.toml:
[versions]
agp = "8.4.1"
kotlin = "1.9.0"
coreKtx = "1.13.1"
junit = "4.13.2"
junitVersion = "1.1.5"
espressoCore = "3.5.1"
lifecycleRuntimeKtx = "2.8.1"
activityCompose = "1.9.0"
composeBom = "2023.08.00"
room = "2.6.1"
roomCommon = "2.6.1"
runtimeLivedata = "1.6.8"
org-jetbrains-kotlin-android = "1.8.0"


[libraries]
androidx-core-ktx = { group = "androidx.core", name = "core-ktx", version.ref = "coreKtx" }
junit = { group = "junit", name = "junit", version.ref = "junit" }
androidx-junit = { group = "androidx.test.ext", name = "junit", version.ref = "junitVersion" }
androidx-espresso-core = { group = "androidx.test.espresso", name = "espresso-core", version.ref = "espressoCore" }
androidx-lifecycle-runtime-ktx = { group = "androidx.lifecycle", name = "lifecycle-runtime-ktx", version.ref = "lifecycleRuntimeKtx" }
androidx-activity-compose = { group = "androidx.activity", name = "activity-compose", version.ref = "activityCompose" }
androidx-compose-bom = { group = "androidx.compose", name = "compose-bom", version.ref = "composeBom" }
androidx-ui = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui" }
androidx-ui-graphics = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-graphics" }
androidx-ui-tooling = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-tooling" }
androidx-ui-tooling-preview = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-tooling-preview" }
androidx-ui-test-manifest = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-test-manifest" }
androidx-ui-test-junit4 = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-test-junit4" }
androidx-material3 = { group = "androidx.compose.material3", name = "material3" }
room-ktx = { group = "androidx.room", name = "room-ktx", version.ref = "room" }
androidx-room-common = { group = "androidx.room", name = "room-common", version.ref = "roomCommon" }
androidx-runtime-livedata = { group = "androidx.compose.runtime", name = "runtime-livedata", version.ref = "runtimeLivedata" }


[plugins]
android-application = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }
jetbrains-kotlin-android = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" }
org-jetbrains-kotlin-kapt = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt", version.ref = "org-jetbrains-kotlin-android" }

Build.gradle.kts(App):
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt) apply false

}

Build.gradle.kts(module):
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
    alias(libs.plugins.org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.tutorialfollowing"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.tutorialfollowing"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
        dataBinding =true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.1"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
    implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.graphics)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.androidx.material3)
    implementation(libs.androidx.room.common)
    implementation(libs.room.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.runtime.livedata)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    androidTestImplementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.junit4)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.manifest)
}

From some source I have found online of people getting similar errors is that there may be  due to some kind of misconfiguration in the project setup. I have tried changing it but was still getting the same errors.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You need to add the necessary dependencies room-compiler and room-runtime, upgrade Kotlin to version 2.0.0 and add the KSP plugin.
In build.gradle.kts(:app)
plugins {
    //...
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinAndroidKsp)
}

dependecies {
    // ...
    implementation(libs.androidx.room.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.room.runtime)
    ksp(libs.androidx.room.compiler)
}

build.gradle.kts(project)
plugins {
    // ...
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinAndroidKsp) apply false
}

libs.versions.toml
[versions]
kotlin = "2.0.0"
room = "2.6.1"
ksp = "2.0.0-1.0.22"

[libraries]
androidx-room-ktx = { group = "androidx.room", name = "room-ktx", version.ref = "room" }
androidx-room-compiler = { group = "androidx.room", name = "room-compiler", version.ref = "room" }
androidx-room-runtime = { group = "androidx.room", name = "room-runtime", version.ref = "room" }

[plugins]
kotlinAndroidKsp = { id = "com.google.devtools.ksp", version.ref = "ksp" }


should i just add these dependencies or do i also need to remove anything such as 'kapt' dependencies for example  ?

Yes, you need to replace the kapt with ksp

thank you so much , I followed your advice as well a enabling the latest version of jetpack compose and this has solved the error problems.  however when I run the application there is a white blank screen and nothing happens.

Happy coding...!

@user25678140: That sounds like another question you can post. If Amardurai's answer solved the problem from your question you should accept it by clicking the check mark on the left.
